# Chart.js Example Diagramm don't show

Tags: chart.js

I found an Example of using Chart.js and to create an HTML file. 
this Example worked just fine. Now I wanted to use chart.js locally. 
Therefore I switched the following line:

```
// <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/0.2.0/Chart.min.js"
```

into:

```
<script src="C:\Temp\Chart.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

(The file: Chart.js is copied into this folder)
```

Now, the code is not working and there you can see no chart

The code on this Diagramm is:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Chart.js demo</title>

<script src="C:\Temp\Chart.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
// <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/0.2.0/Chart.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

```
<h1>Chart.js Sample</h1>

<canvas id="countries" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
<script>
    var pieData = [
        {
            value: 20,
            color:"#878BB6"
        },
        {
            value : 40,
            color : "#4ACAB4"
        },
        {
            value : 10,
            color : "#FF8153"
        },
        {
            value : 30,
            color : "#FFEA88"
        }
    ];
    // Get the context of the canvas element we want to select
    var countries= document.getElementById("countries").getContext("2d");
    new Chart(countries).Pie(pieData);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax to be used to load the JavaScript file from you local folder would be as follows:

```
<script src="file:///C:/Temp\Chart.js"></script>
```

Browsers however won't allow you to load local resources and you should see a corresponding error message on the console. Most browsers have an option to allow such access but you need to explicitly enable this since it makes your system vulnerable.

> In case you're using Chrome, you can get further information from the
>   article at
>   https://chrisbitting.com/2014/03/04/allow-local-file-access-in-chrome-windows/